# incredible slow build with android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

I know this is a very common question but I want to understand what is going on in my situation. I have a very small project on android studio and the build time at the IDE startup is something as 5 seconds. Then when I run the project gradle takes 1 to 3 minutes to build and some extra minutes to start the app in my real device or in a genymotion virtual device. I think that is not acceptable since if I have to test some not clear minimal part of code I have to invest a day to found the solution. I have to specify that I had take some advices from similar questions around the web as activate gradle deamon and set it to work offline but nothing helped. My question is: I have to accept the situation or there is some way to speed up workflow? Is necessary to rebuild all the project every time even if only a row of code is changed?

Comment: Yeap, it is slow and nothing can be done about it. Except unit testing your code as plain Java as much as possible and run the emulator only for when you need to test the user interface interaction.

Comment: @Lucho What if I have to test the UI behaviour? I think that for a beginner like me learn about the android UI through testing and trying is a nightmare!

Comment: a better computer might be of help and also relying on the layout preview in the Android Studio for small UI changes. If you want try to use Android Studio 2.0 Preview, which Google claims it will be "super fast" - http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0-preview